# invalid xpath expression python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, automated-tests

I am trying to get all xpaths that start with something, but when I test it out, it says my xpath is invalid.

This is my xpath:

```
xpath = "//*[contains(@id,'ClubDetails_"+ str(team) +"']"
```

Which outputs when I print:

```
//*[contains(@id,'ClubDetails_1']
```

Here is HTML:

```html
<div id="ClubDetails_1_386" class="fadeout">
   <div class="MapListDetail">
      <div>Bev Garman</div>
      <a href="javascript:DoMailTo('armadaswim@aol.com')">armadaswim@aol.com</a>
   </div>
   <div class="MapListDetail">
      <div>Rolling Hills Country Day School</div>
      <div>26444 Crenshaw Blvd</div>
      <div>Rolling Hills Estates, CA 90274</div>
   </div>
   <div class="MapListDetailOtherLocs_1">
      <div>This club also swims at other locations</div>
      <a href="javascript:ShowOtherLocs(386,'La Mirada Armada')"><span class="show_them_link">show them...</span></a>
   </div>
</div>
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: You have not closed the `)` parenthesis from the `contains` call: `xpath = "//*[contains(@id,'ClubDetails_"+ str(team) +"')]"`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative can be use pattern to match an ID starting with some text and get all those element in a list and then iterate list one by one and check the condition whether id attribute of that element contains the team is you wants.

You can match the pattern in CSS selector as below :

```
div[id^='ClubDetails_']
```

And this is how in xpath :

```
//div[starts-with(@id, 'ClubDetails_')]
```

Code sample:

```
expectedid = "1_386"
clubdetails = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[id^='ClubDetails_']")
for item in clubdetails:
    elementid = item.get_attribute('id')
    expectedid in elementid
    // further code
```